# do_action not firing in wp_ajax_{action}

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to set a hook inside a wp_ajax action. The ajax function works and if I add the code from send_mail() it also works.

**plugins/myplugin/ajax.php**
(file is included in myplugin.php)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_theaction','theaction');
function theaction () {
    //do stuff
    do_action('send_mail');
}
```

**themes/mytheme/mail.php**
(file is included in functions.php)

```
add_action('send_mail','send_mail'); 
function send_mail () {
    wp_mail('user@example.com','Subject','Hello');
}
```

It seems like 'do_action' gets ignored

Comment: Have you tried calling `send_mail()` directly from `the_action()`?

Comment: @GentlemanMax yes, this works